# acts_as_votable not working when I upvote/downvote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, voting, acts-as-votable

I am trying to allow `treatment` to be votable with upvotes or downvotes but the methods provided by act_as_votable don't seem to be working as intended. When I try to display the sum of upvotes-downvotes it returns 0 each time, implying votes aren't registering like they should.

My `treatments_controller.rb`

```
def upvote
  @treatment = Treatment.find(params[:id])
  @treatment.upvote_by @current_user

  render 'show'
end

def downvote
  @treatment = Treatment.find(params[:id])
  @treatment.downvote_by @current_user

  redirect_to treatments_path
end
```

My `treatment.rb`

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_votable


 has_many :review
 has_one :service


    def score
  self.get_upvotes.size - self.get_downvotes.size
end

end
```

My `routes.rb`

```
resources :treatments do
  member do
    put "like", to: "treatments#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "treatments#downvote"
  end
end
```

And my `treatments/show.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <h3><%= @treatment.name %></h3></br></br>
 <h3>
           <%= link_to "upvote", like_treatment_path(@treatment), method: :put %></br>
            <%= link_to "downvote", dislike_treatment_path(@treatment), method: :put %></br>
            <%= @treatment.score %></br> </h3>
```

The server log says the following

```
Started PUT "/treatments/1/like" for ::1 at 2015-12-09 16:22:14 +0000
Processing by TreatmentsController#upvote as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"hQnqV+OZ6m/9kFnr5YH6j563DIjyKfA4K/8fH6kpFbXbJRbsHCcNYn1AX4usZmUNXPlnFpxHMwTM8ilFxcbdhQ==", "id"=>"1"}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  Treatment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "treatments".* FROM "treatments" WHERE "treatments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Treatment"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Treatment"], ["vote_flag", "f"]]
  Rendered treatments/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
Completed 200 OK in 569ms (Views: 563.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Look at your server logs when you click up/downvote - see anything wrong? What's the HTTP response? Are there any votes in the DB afterwards?

Comment: @Kristján I added the server log to the original post

Comment: Your log shows no `INSERT`s for the new vote. Is `@current_user.nil?` Should that be `current_user`?

Comment: I think you are right, i changed it to  `current_user`. But I am now getting the error `undefined local variable or method `current_user' ` even though it is defined in the `ApplicationHelper` in another method `def signed_in?`

Comment: Helpers aren't loaded in controllers unless you've explicitly `include`d them, and naming things the same [doesn't make them the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138265/variable-defined-in-a-function-throws-nameerror-global-name-not-defined-when-us/34138511#34138511). You probably want to write a `current_user` method in `ApplicationController`, or run a `before_action` that sets `@current_user`, which will persist for the duration of the action.

Comment: @FergusMorton `ApplicationHelper` methods are visible to your views, if you want to use them in your controllers you'll have to either `include ApplicationHelper` in your `application_controller.rb` or define your method in that file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Kristjan I realised there was no insertion happening. I defined current_user within the upvote and downvote methods. The revised working versions look like so.

```
 def upvote
  current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  @treatment = Treatment.find(params[:id])
  @treatment.upvote_by current_user

  render 'show'
end

def downvote
  current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  @treatment = Treatment.find(params[:id])
  @treatment.downvote_by current_user

  render 'show'
end
```